# Cancel user creation from hook_user_presave

Tags: 7, users

I created a module that links to Taleo (Talent Management system). When creating a Drupal user, automatically a Taleo Candidate is made.

This works like a charm. But sometimes Taleo answers with an error (example: a candidate with email address info@example.com already exists)

Is there an easy way to cancel the creation of the user from within 'hook_user_presave'? Now the error messages is showed, but the Drupal user is made anyway.

```
function taleo_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    global $client_taleo;
    $session = _taleo_login();
    $error = 0;

    if(!isset($edit['field_taleo_id'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
        // NOT LINKED TO TALEO

        $params = array(
            'in0' => $session,
            'in1' => array('id' => '', 'rank' => '', 'status' => '0-Available', 
            'firstName'     => @$edit['field_first_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 
            'lastName'      => @$edit['field_last_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 
            'phone'         => @$edit['field_phone_number'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'zipCode'       => @$edit['field_zip_code'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'country'       => @$edit['field_country'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'textResume'    => @$edit['field_text_resume'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'lastUpdated'   => date('c'),
            'email'             => @$edit['mail'])
        );

        try{
            $edit['field_taleo_id'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $client_taleo->__call('createCandidate', $params);
        } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            $error = 1;
            $error_message = check_plain("ERROR: " . $fault->faultcode . "-" . $fault->faultstring);
            drupal_set_message($error_message);
            watchdog('taleo', $error_message, array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
            return array();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `hook_validate()` will be a better place to check if taleo accepts new user data or not. If it didnt set an error using `form_set_error()` for Email Field.

I am not sure if `presave()` is the right hook to stop creation of user.

> A user account is about to be created or updated.
>
> This hook is primarily intended for modules that want to store
>   properties in the serialized {users}.data column, which is
>   automatically loaded whenever a user account object is loaded, modules
>   may add to $edit['data'] in order to have their data serialized on
>   save.

Comment: Basic idea is correct, but you want to add a new validation function to [user_account_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7).

Comment: @MPD Yes need to add a new validation function.

Comment: [hook_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7) is for modules implementing a content type.

Comment: I thought about this option before your answer  Kantu, but the answer is he right one. I'll post the code for whoever needs it.

Comment: What if the user save comes from a batch operation?  For example, if on admin/people, a user blocks a user?  I don't think validation functions for user_account_form would be run in this case.  It seems to me canceling the save in hook_user_presave would take care of all circumstances.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of [hook_user('validate')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6) used in Drupal 6 doesn't exist in Drupal 7. For that, you need to add a form validation handler to [user_register_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_form/7), and use [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) when Taleo returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code to check if Taleo (or other sources) gave an error, if so: a form error will be shown.

```
function taleo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
        $form['#validate'][] = 'taleo_form_validate';
        return $form;
    }
}

function taleo_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    // If previous validation didn't pass, return
    if (form_get_errors()) return;

    global $client_taleo, $user, $taleo_id;

    $session = _taleo_login();
    $user = user_load($user->uid);

    // NOT LINKED TO TALEO
    if(strlen($user->field_taleo_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) == 0) {
        $params = array(
            'in0' => $session,
            'in1' => array('id' => '', 'rank' => '', 'status' => '0-Available', 
            'firstName'     => @$form_state['values']['field_first_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 
            'lastName'      => @$form_state['values']['field_last_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], 
            'phone'         => @$form_state['values']['field_phone_number'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'zipCode'       => @$form_state['values']['field_zip_code'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'country'       => @$form_state['values']['field_country'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'textResume'    => @$form_state['values']['field_text_resume'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            'lastUpdated'   => date('c'),
            'email'         => @$form_state['values']['mail'])
        );

        try{
            $taleo_id = $client_taleo->__call('createCandidate', $params);
        } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            form_set_error('', check_plain($fault->faultstring));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't add the function to the form validation handlers, it is not executed.

Comment: I know, I added it to the code... You never know someone can use this piece of code.