# Is it possible to cancel the creation of user without triggering an error?

Tags: 7, users, hooks, emails

I have a problem with account creation spam, in which a bot or other bad actor tries to create accounts using somebody elses email address. The owner of the email address flags the verification email as spam, and I get tagged by my email provider for sending spam.

I'd like to try a "shadow ban" sort of situation, in which it appears the account creation is successful, but the verification email is not sent and the account is not created.

According to [Cancel user creation from hook_user_presave](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48046/cancel-user-creation-from-hook-user-presave) hook_user_presave() won't work.

I thought about using hook_mail_alter() to cancel the verification emails, and then hook_user_insert() to immediately delete the user (or maybe save the user ids, for a cron job to delete later). This seems like it could work, but I'm learning Drupal as I go, so I'm hoping somebody with more experience will be able to think of something simpler.